# Cause of ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the following query, I get the following error:

> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

```
select customer_name, count(product_name) Total 
from customer c
  join orders o
    on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
  join products p
    on o.product_id=p.product_id
where p.product_category='books'
AND order_date between '1-Aug-19' AND sysdate
AND count(product_name)>3
group by customer_name
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change the query to this:

```
select customer_name
       , count(product_name) Total 
from customer c 
join orders o on c.customer_id=o.customer_id 
join products p on o.product_id=p.product_id 
where p.product_category='books' 
AND order_date between '1-Aug-19' AND sysdate 
group by customer_name 
having count(product_name)>3;
```

Use `HAVING` instead `WHERE` when comparing aggreagtes.
Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e167a3fa2e6e07840d6626b966b94f3)